# Finding coordinate of vertice of triangle given 2 other vertices and angle (Coordinate Geometry)

Tags: polar-coordinates

Two points $A$ and $B$ and  have coordinates (-1, 0) and (7, 2) respectively. The point $C(x,y)$ where $x>0$ and $y>0$, lies on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ and $ACB=90^\circ$ .

Find the coordinates of $C$.

I know that $CA$ and $CB$ will have the same length, so I tried using the distance formula to come up with 2 equations whereby $CA$ = $CB$, but I ended up with both $x^2$ and $y^2$, at this point which I' stuck.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the Point $$C(x;y)$$ you have two conditions:
$$(x+1)+y^2=(x-7)^2+(y-2)^2$$ and $$y=-4x+13$$
can you solve it now?

Comment: Definitely, thanks so much for pointing this out. Was stuck at your first equation.

Comment: Substituted $y$ into the first equation to solve for $x$, I ended up with 0=0. I don't think this was what I am supposed to end up with?

Comment: i think we have not used that the angle $ACB>90^{\circ}$ is

Comment: the $$\cos(ACB)$$ is then negative

Comment: additionally it must be $$2((x-7)^2+(y-2)^2)<68$$

Comment: Edited my original post- $ \angle ACD $ is meant to be $90^\circ$. Even when using this property, I still cannot solve the equation because I am stuck at a single equation with 2 variables $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

The mid point $D$ of $AB$ is $(3,1)$ and the point $C$ can be got by rotating $DA$ by $90^\circ$. Hence it is $3+i \pm i((3+i) - (-1)) = 3+i \pm (4i -1)$. Hence the possible coordinates of $C$ are $(2,5)$ or $(4,-3)$

Comment: Interesting, (4, -3) is the correct answer. However, this is high school math where complex numbers haven't been covered though, do you've another way without touching complex numbers?